How would I go about fixing a loose gutter?
What’s the best way to go about loose gutters for new home owners…
Hey guys, so this is becoming a major issue now that’s it’s spring time. Only a portion of our gutter was slightly loose when we purchased our home (As is) just over 2 year ago. We wanted to wait until we redid our elevated patio before putting any ladders and/or more than 3 people at a time. It’s somewhat worn. But as of today, during a passing rain shower, the gutter has been pulled even further away from the house and I’m afraid it’s going to be ripped completely off. (about 6 ft of the 25-30ft gutter is now detached) It’s about a 15-20ft height from the patio to the roof but it’s much closer to reach from the second floor kitchen window. But it does extend about 3-4 ft out from the home and would be super risky by just leaning out the window. Are there any recommendations for how to go about fixing this. I’m a stay at home mom and our family is on one income so just hiring someone is really a last resort. I do have some pictures and videos but it won’t allow me to add. Please help! 

Gutters are usually attached with hangers.  Plastic gutters have hangers they fit in, an aluminum gutters have the hangers inside at the top.  Either type is held by screws.  If the screws came loose, then might be better to move the hangers over an inch for new screw holes, or use longer screws if in roof trusses/rafters.

I would feel much better about doing this on a ladder than leaning out a window, if only because you can only reach so much gutter length from a window.  You can rent a ladder from Home Depot for $31 for 4 hours in my area.  4 hours should be plenty of time to relocate the gutter hangers or add some new ones, and if not, the ladders are only $44 for the whole day.
